# how can when i click the object of button show new object of form2?(C#-Windows form application)

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, object, button

> private void gunaButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
> {
> for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
> {
> GunaButton btn = new GunaButton();
>
> ```
>                 //add btn to flowlayoutpanel to arrange buttons
>                 flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(btn);
>
>                 Form2 f = new Form2();
>
>                 //how can i make object of button show new  object of form2
>
>                 btn.Click +=new System.EventHandler(f.ShowDialog());
>
>                 
>             }
>
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```cs
    btn.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btn_Click);
    
    private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Form2 f2 = new Form2();
       f2.ShowDialog();
    }
```